# Keyboard shortcut for Android Emulator running on Mac OS X

Tags: android, macos, emulation

I've searched around, and I just can't find certain keyboard shortcuts for the Android Emulator. Specifically,the equivalent of enter/click. I've found that fn+left arrow will move from highlighting one icon to another but no actions.

Just clicking the doesn't seem to have any effects on the Android emulator. (I'm running OS X Lion). Perhaps I need to configure something?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you don't have **Keyboard support** set to **yes** in you AVD (Hardware properties) and that's why your keyboard is not working.
Then most of the keys will work as expected.